# Appsync + Elasticsearch : Communication error while executing a request to OpenSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-elasticsearch

I am trying to do a quick poc between Appsync (graphql) and ElasticSearch(V7.10) but i am getting the below communication error when Appsync(resolver) is trying to invoke ES . Its a simple graphql query.

i tried following this tutorial for this poc : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-elasticsearch-resolvers.html

Cloudwatch Logs is enabled for both appsync and elasticsearch, but not much on this error.
Any help on this is much appreciated.

**Bellow are the details.**

ES : Version 7.10 (also tried with OpenSearch 1.0, but same error), its within the vpc, appsync is created withing the same region as the vpc.

**Error :**

```
{
    "data": {
      "allPosts": null
    },
    "errors": [
      {
        "path": [
          "allPosts"
        ],
        "data": null,
        "errorType": "OpenSearch:RuntimeException",
        "errorInfo": null,
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 2,
            "column": 3,
            "sourceName": null
          }
        ],
        "message": "Communication error while executing a request to OpenSearch."
      }
    ]
  }
```

**Request Mapping Template (Resolver)**

```
{
"version":"2017-02-28",
"operation":"GET",
"path":"/item_catlog_001/_doc/_search",
"params":{
    "body": {
        "from": 0,
        "size": 50,
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        }
    }
}
}
```

**IAM's role on Appsync end**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "es:ESHttpDelete",
                "es:ESHttpHead",
                "es:ESHttpGet",
                "es:ESHttpPost",
                "es:ESHttpPut"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:es:ap-southeast-2:*:domain/helloworld/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Trust relationships**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "appsync.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Access policy at ES/OS end**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:ap-southeast-2:*:domain/helloworld/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/service-role/appsync-ds-es-57leg5-vpc-helloworld-o53f5"
      },
      "Action": [
        "es:ESHttpDelete",
        "es:ESHttpHead",
        "es:ESHttpGet",
        "es:ESHttpPost",
        "es:ESHttpPut"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:ap-southeast-2:*:domain/helloworld/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

thanks
Vasu

Comment: I have a similar issue, and I believe the problem is that AppSync is actually outside of your VPC and it can't reach OpenSearch. You can access OpenSearch from an EC2 instance as long as you create a load balancer which will forward the appropriate port

Comment: Have you figured out what was wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have ElasticSearch behind a VPC you'll see this error. Check this out

> AWS AppSync supports using Amazon OpenSearch Service from domains that you have provisioned in your own AWS account, provided they don’t exist inside a VPC

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-elasticsearch-resolvers.html

This is an issue that has vexed me as well - the best solution I've managed is to create a lambda  proxy behind the same VPC as elastic search; have the lambda accept your ES search string pass it along and return the results to your AppSync resolver - AppSync can  use lambdas behind a VPC  (but for some reason not  OpenSearch)